# Why are Mobius map conformal at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Why are Mobius map conformal at infinity? I think I'm missing a subtlety!

So we know an analytic function, $f$, is conformal at $z$ iff $f'(z) \neq 0$

But we see that the derivative of Mobius transformation at $\infty$ is $0$. I am told that we just need to look at $\frac{1}{z}$ to see that the Mobius transformation is conformal at $\infty$. And of course looking at the Mobius transformation evaluated at $\frac{1}{z}$, and differentiating with respect to $z$ we see that at $z = 0$ the result is non-zero. Showing that the map is conformal at $\infty$.

But why are we doing this substitution? What exactly is going on here?

Comment: The derivative at $\infty$ is not defined. To investigate the mapping properties, one can consider the behaviour of $f(1/z)$ at $0$. Or one can look at the sphere via stereographic projection to see that there the point corresponding to $\infty$ is not special at all.

Comment: Ah, of course. Do I understand correctly that the derivative of a function is NEVER defined at infinity? Due to the nature of the definition of a derivative? As we can no longer talk about a neighbourhood of infinity?

Comment: @harry dunlop: Derivatives are calculated with respect to a coordinate chart, and "$z$" is a coordinate precisely on the complement of $\infty$ in the sphere, while "$1/z$" is a coordinate on the complement of $0$.

Comment: $f'(\infty):=\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} z\big(f(z)-f(\infty)\big)$